# balloonAutoPan в скрытом контейнере не правильно позиционирует при Placemark.balloon.open()

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

На сайте несколько карт которые переключаются табами. На каждую добавил по 1 метке с балуном, который имеет кастомный макет, хочу чтобы при переключении между табами балун был по умолчанию открыт.
При использовании метода Placemark.balloon.open(); 
первый экран который был открыт при загрузке страницы открывается нормально, 
последующие позиционируются в координатах первой метки.

UPD.
Вопрос решен вот полный код:

```
var myMap0;
var myMap1;
// Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.

ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
  // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
  // заданным id ("map").

  myMap0 = new ymaps.Map('map', {
     // При инициализации карты обязательно нужно указать
     // её центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
     center: [45.013479, 38.995166], // краснодар
     zoom: 16,
     controls: ['zoomControl']
  });

  myMap0.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

  myMap1 = new ymaps.Map('map1', {
    // При инициализации карты обязательно нужно указать
    // её центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
    center: [55.753215, 37.622504], // Москва
    zoom: 10,
   controls: ['zoomControl']
 });

myMap1.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

// Создание макета балуна на основе Twitter Bootstrap.
  MyBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div class="popover top">' +
    '<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>' +
    '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
    '<div class="popover-inner">' +
    '$[[options.contentLayout observeSize minWidth=280 maxWidth=280 maxHeight=200]]' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>', {
    / * Строит экземпляр макета на основе шаблона и добавляет его в родительский HTML-элемент. */
     build: function () {
       this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);
       this._$element = $('.popover', this.getParentElement());
       this.applyElementOffset();
       this._$element.find('.close').on('click', $.proxy(this.onCloseClick, this));
     },

     /*Удаляет содержимое макета из DOM. */
    clear: function () {
      this._$element.find('.close').off('click');
      this.constructor.superclass.clear.call(this);
    },

    /* Метод будет вызван системой шаблонов АПИ при изменении размеров вложенного макета. */
   onSublayoutSizeChange: function () {
     MyBalloonLayout.superclass.onSublayoutSizeChange.apply(this, arguments);
     if(!this._isElement(this._$element)) {
       return;
     }

    this.applyElementOffset();
    this.events.fire('shapechange');
  },

  /* Сдвигаем балун, чтобы "хвостик" указывал на точку привязки. */
  applyElementOffset: function () {
    this._$element.css({
      left: -(this._$element[0].offsetWidth / 2),
      top: -(this._$element[0].offsetHeight + this._$element.find('.arrow')[0].offsetHeight)
    });
  },

  /*Закрывает балун при клике на крестик, кидая событие "userclose" на макете.*/
 onCloseClick: function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    this.events.fire('userclose');
  },

  /*Используется для автопозиционирования (balloonAutoPan). */
  getShape: function () {
    if(!this._isElement(this._$element)) {
      return MyBalloonLayout.superclass.getShape.call(this);
    }      
    var position = this._$element.position();
    return new ymaps.shape.Rectangle(new ymaps.geometry.pixel.Rectangle([
      [position.left, position.top], [position.left + this._$element[0].offsetWidth,
      position.top + this._$element[0].offsetHeight + this._$element.find('.arrow')[0].offsetHeight]
    ]));
  },  
  /*Проверяем наличие элемента (в ИЕ и Опере его еще может не быть).*/
  _isElement: function (element) {
    return element && element[0] && element.find('.arrow')[0];
  }
});

// Создание вложенного макета содержимого балуна.
MyBalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  '<h3 class="popover-title">$[properties.balloonHeader]</h3>' +
  '<div class="popover-content">$[properties.balloonContent]</div>'
);  

myPlacemark0 = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap0.getCenter(), { 
  balloonHeader: "Наш адрес:",
  balloonContent: "г.Краснодар",
},
{
  iconLayout: 'default#image',
  iconImageHref: 'images/map.png', // картинка иконки
  iconImageSize: [64, 100], // размер иконки
  iconImageOffset: [-32, -100], // позиция иконки

  balloonShadow: false,
  balloonLayout: MyBalloonLayout,
  balloonContentLayout: MyBalloonContentLayout,
  balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
  balloonOffset: [0, -10]
});

myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap1.getCenter(), { 
  balloonHeader: "Наш адрес:",
  balloonContent: "г.Москва",
},
{
  iconLayout: 'default#image',
  iconImageHref: 'images/map.png', // картинка иконки
  iconImageSize: [64, 100], // размер иконки
  iconImageOffset: [-32, -100], // позиция иконки

  balloonShadow: false,
  balloonLayout: MyBalloonLayout,
  balloonContentLayout: MyBalloonContentLayout,
  balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
  balloonOffset: [0, -10]
});

/* Добавляем метки на карту */
myMap0.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark0);
myPlacemark0.balloon.open();

myMap1.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);

$('#tabs').on('tabsactivate',function (event, ui) {
  window['myMap'+ui.newTab.index()].container.fitToViewport();
  window['myPlacemark'+ui.newTab.index()].balloon.open();    
});
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, на котором видна проблема. Вероятно, вы вызываете метод на одной и той же метке для каждого таба, из-за чего карта позиционируется "неправильно".

Comment: все решил. там была проблема  в том что для табов использовал jquery-ui версии 1.11 а использовал триггер переключения 'tabshow' от версии 1.8 вместо 'tabsactivate'